# How to make IE 11 wrap flexbox items when the flex container is inside a floating element?

Tags: css-float, internet-explorer-11, flexbox

I'm trying to add a flexbox element to the content area of a two column layout. The layout has a fixed width sidebar and fluid content. It uses `float: left` and negative margins to achieve this.

The goal is for the flex container to be 100% width of the parent. Flex items should be displayed in rows, with excess items wrapping to the next row.

The straight-forward approach works fine in Firefox and Chrome:

```
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.flex-item {
    flex: 1 0 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

...

<div class="flex-container">
   <div class="flex-item">Item</div>
   <!-- more items here -->
   <div class="flex-item">Item</div>
</div>
```

Full example (works in FF and Chrome, but not IE 11):
http://jsfiddle.net/btc9chw0/3/

**The problem**

In Internet Explorer 11, all items are displayed on a single row. They never wrap to the next row, even when there are lots of items. This causes the page to become much wider than the browser window.

After lots of experimentation, it appears that this is somehow related to the fact that the flex container is inside a `float: left` element. Removing the `float` allows items to wrap correctly, but breaks other parts of the layout. The content area can have other content in addition to the flexbox, and some of that content needs to use `float: left` and `clear: both`. Without a floating parent element, a `clear: both` would push everything below the sidebar. Giving `.flex-container` a fixed width also fixes the problem, but in this case we want it be 100% width.

Firefox screenshot:

[image: Firefox - items wrap]

IE 11 screenshot:

[image: IE 11 - items don't wrap]

**The question**

Is there are way to make flex items wrap to the next row in IE 11 when the parent of the flexbox container has "float: left"?

*Disclaimer: Please disregard, for the moment, the fact that this layout uses both floats and flexbox instead of just one or the other. In this case, flexbox is a nice-to-have enhancement for one part of the page, while the general layout must be more robust.*

Answer (score 1):

The underlying issue here actually has to do with the auto measurement of a container in a shrink-to-fit context. By making `.content` have a min-width of 100% you've left the max-width to auto so the browser needs to measure the content to know its max-width to shrink down around it.

In IE, complete layout will be done to get the exact result with no limitations if none were set (as is the case here, we actually have infinite space since we can scroll and you have limited the width anywhere within its ancestor tree). Webkit and Gecko had made some changes in the past to avoid having to actually do layout and do an approximation, even though the actual measurement results were incorrect since they didn't know how big other (shrink-to-fit containers were) they decided the perf benefits were worth the tradeoff. With Gecko, Webkit and Blink (due to forking from webkit) all using this same behavior we changed our implementation to match this in Microsoft Edge and so we render the same as Firefox, Chrome, Safari. To get the same result in IE11 you'll need to provide a maximum width constraint when in a shrink-to-fit context (floats, abspos, table cell, etc).

Ultimately I prefer the IE behavior because it actually makes sense and is consistent. If there is enough space to lay out the content, the layout shouldn't change (as is the case here). Here is a [simpler example](http://jsfiddle.net/xzt063uv/2/) showing why this approximation can cause issues, there is still enough room in the viewport to render the same result in each case but because they can't determine the actual dimensions of the floated blocks you get different results in Chrome/Firefox/Safari/Edge; while in IE they produce the same consistent result.

Sorry for the long reply, but I wanted to provide the context for why IE seems incorrect here.

Let me know if you need any further clarification.